# Find angle form set of images

Tags: image-processing, neural-network, angle

I have set of 2000 plane images similar to image below. Plane has different angle on every image. Image size is 512x512 and in every image is always this same plane.

[image]

My goal is to find angle on image which is not in test set.

So far I tried:

- **Harris corner detection**, but in every image Harris gives me differnt
  amount of points, event for images with very similar position.
- **Hough Lines Transform** to find the longest line and get inclination to the axis X.
- **Corelation** - this method gives the best results, but it take really long time and angels are only rough.
- **Neural network**

  - Back porpagation to train image from Harris points and hough lines transform, but without any success.

I so 3D object in STP file, but I have no idea how to use it, to solve my problem.
It would be nice to get any sugestion of method, article or example.

Comment: Is it always the same plane?

Comment: What do you mean by the **angle**? Are the images taken from different viewpoints?

Comment: @dhanushka yes, thats mean that in some pictures you see bottom of the plane in other top and so on.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, a [convolutional neural network](http://white.stanford.edu/teach/index.php/An_Introduction_to_Convolutional_Neural_Networks) (CNN) will help you a great deal here. The performance will be great at detecting angles.

But here is the problem, depending of how you define the output to be and the number of layers (no more than three should be enough), the training can be very costly. For example, you could [have one single output](http://white.stanford.edu/teach/images/d/df/Mylenet.png) that could give you a real number which indicates the angle. Training this should be costly, but it is normal in CNNs. However, if you say you want to [have 360 outputs](http://parse.ele.tue.nl/cluster/2/CNNArchitecture.jpg) (one for each angle in a 360 degree system), in that case the training will be a very painful and unpleasant long experience; the performance could be better, but not significantly.

(I wanted to write this as a comment to your question first, but I don't have enough reputation to do that yet, sorry.)

Comment: it sounds like a big step forward for me. I will try to implement it. However I can use radian scale if output can be decimal. Should I use every pixel as input? Or e.i. corner points will be enought in your opinion?

Comment: Great question. But this is the beauty of CNNs: it will learn by itself whether or not corners are a good feature in detecting the angle. :)  You and I know, intuitively, that the edges and corners, and lines will help in the estimation of the angle, but the CNN will learn which one is more important than the other and what is the relationship between them.  CNNs (and Deep Learning in general) is an exciting field right now because of problems like the one you are investigating.  To speed things up, I recommend you a C++ implementation.